# Non-AirPrint-enabled printer for iOS

Tags: ios, printing, wifi, airprint, ios-bluetooth

For non-AirPrint enabled printer Apple does not have any in built API. 
I learned that we can add a WiFi module to a printer. So my question is:

- If I add WiFi module to a printer, will it be AirPrint-enabled?
- If not: can a non-AirPrint-enabled printer be made AirPrint-enabled by other means?
- If I get a non-AirPrint-enabled printer is it possible to connect to it from an iPad?
- If yes what is the protocol I should use?
- Is there any open source library on this?

I found the following one: https://github.com/opentable/star-printing.

But from the documentation I could not understand: is it only for AirPrint enabled printers?

Below are the ways I can connect a desktop printer using iPad I guess.

1. WIFI enabled
2. Bluetooth enabled
3. Bonjour enabled printer
4. Networked printers (printer having same ip segment with iPad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to answer all your questions:

- `If I add a wifi module, will my printer be AirPrint enabled?`
- `Can a non-AirPrint printer be made into an AirPrint printer?`

No. You need an AirPrint compatible printer, simply making it available over WiFi does not make it an AirPrint printer, and you cannot change the device to make it an AirPrint printer.

- `If not, can I still use it?`

Yes. However, it will require that you directly open connection with the printer (via a socket) and send the data that way. It's really not too hard to do. There are likely some libraries available, but I haven't specifically tried. The code to open the port and send a data blob is pretty trivial, assuming you have the PCL data already.

- `Can I connect to a WiFi printer?`

Yes, as described above.

- `... Bluetooth?`

Yes, but only on MFi (Made For iOS) printers.

- `... Bonjour`

Yes, via the built in print dialog.

- `... Networked`

This could probably be done the same way as the WiFi printing, but I haven't tried it yet.

Hope that helps, let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very helpful. Can you please point me any library, as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I'm not familiar with any libraries offhand, though communication via WiFi is as easy as opening a socket, as mentioned. I made a [super simple gist](https://gist.github.com/shortstuffsushi/e0a0252e70a6f42b1049) to demonstrate.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming,...

- you have a Mac(Book) running OS X,
- this Mac's hostname is ***`mymac`***,
- its IP address is ***`192.168.111.111`***,
- it has a *shared* printer installed named ***`abcd`*** (does *NOT* need to be AirPrint-capable!), and
- the printer share requires no authentication (put *`DefaultAuthType none`* into `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`),

...then you can make your computer act as an AirPrint gateway to the `abcd` queue available to iOS clients.

To test this, just execute the following command in a Terminal.app window (attention, the command will not return -- if you close the Terminal.app window, the effect of the command will be gone!)

```
 dns-sd                 \
   -P AirPrint-abcd     \
   _ipp._tcp,_universal \
   local.               \
   631                  \
   mymac.local.         \
   192.168.111.111      \
         pdl="application/pdf,image/urf"    \
         kind="document"                    \
         priority="1"                       \
         product="Model Name of my Printer" \
         rp="printers/abcd"                 \
         URF="DM3"                          \
         Duplex="T"                         \
         Color="T"                          \
         note="Testing AirPrint via MacBook"\
         txtvers="1"                        \
         qtotal="1"                         \
         printer-type="0x0480FFFC"          \
         printer-state="3"                  \
         air="none"                         \
         UUID="54321abc-1234-1234-abcd-1238e4bdcbf8"
```

You could come up with a script or cron job which executes this command in the background every time the Mac is booted up. This is left as an exercise to the reader.

Additionally, you could run this same command unchanged from a second, completely different Mac on the same network, if the first Mac is providing the shared print queue and all the details above match the first Mac's settings.

---

**Background info:**

The **`dns-sd`** command line utility is meant as a testing and development tool for everybody poking into Bonjour, mDNS (multicast DNS) and DNS-SD (DNS-based Service Discovery).

The **`-P`** parameter to `dns-sd` will make a Bonjour "proxy announcement" to your local LAN/WLAN. The announcement will tell potential AirPrint clients the following info:

- There is an AirPrint device available in your `.local.` domain.
- Its name is `Airprint-abcd`.
- It can be reached via IP address `192.168.111.111` and port `631`.
- Use the print queue name of `printers/abcd` to print to it.
- It can consume PDF and URF raster documents.
- It does not need authentication.
- It can output duplex and color documents.

For details about this utility see *`man dns-sd`*. For more background, see [dns-sd.org](http://www.dns-sd.org/) and [my other answers on similar questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A14598+%5Bairprint%5D).